# Suitable replacement for HTA in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hta, versionupgrade

I'm working in an office that uses something similar to Message of the Day here -> http://www.jhouseconsulting.com/2007/12/28/creating-a-message-of-the-day-banner-using-a-hta-4

But as we're upgrading to Windows 10 and it doesn't support HTA (ignoring IE9 compatibility) this will need replacing.

Question is what can do the same thing, the provisos are:

- Not before Login (so not using Login Banner)
- Only after Login Window
- Should not be close-able except by using the "Agree to this MSG" button
- Text will vary so need easy method to keep text from control(html file?)
- will be distributed by DC (logon script)

This application is used for Acknowledgement of Compliance and security information dissemination.  Thanks for your thoughts,

Comment: You can still run HTAs in Win10 and IE11. The only things you'll miss are the properties defined in HTA tag, i.e. no window appearance control, no single instance, no icon, no selection control etc. If you can live without those properties, everything else works fine + you can apply more modern JS and DOM compared to earlier versions, by using DTD for HTML5 and X-UA of "IE=edge". Apart from the window control, you can hack the most of other properties, since all the HTA's privileges are still in use.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Windows 10 can still run HTAs. If you want to force IE9 mode you can stick a meta tag in the head:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
</head>
```

Comment: Sorry can't use IE9 compatibility, must have a full replacement method

Answer (score 0):

Just give a try with this HTA :
Tested only on Windows 7 (64 bits)

```
<html>
<!--
  MOTD.hta (Message of the Day)
  Written by Jeremy.Saunders@au1.ibm.com on 12/11/06.

-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<title>Message of the Day</title>
<hta:application id="objHTAInfo"
  applicationname="Message of the Day"
  version="1.0"
  border="thin"
  borderstyle="raised"
  caption="yes"
  contextmenu="yes"
  innerborder="no"
  maximizebutton="no"
  minimizebutton="no"
  selection="yes"
  scroll="yes"
  scrollflat="yes"
  showintaskbar="no"
  SysMenu="no"
  SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
>

<style type="text/css">
body {
  font: 13pt arial;
  color: white; 
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient (GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#000000', EndColorStr='#0000FF')
}
p {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
  Option Explicit
  Const ForReading = 1

  Sub Window_Onload
    Dim strMOTDFile, arrCommands, strLogonServer, strCommonPath, strPath, strcurrentPath, strLine, strContents
    Dim i, WshShell, oFSO, objFile
    strMOTDFile = "motd.txt"
    arrCommands = Split(objHTAInfo.commandLine, chr(34))

' Uncomment the next three lines for testing only.
'    For i = 3 to (Ubound(arrCommands) - 1) Step 2
'        Msgbox arrCommands(i)
'    Next

    If Ubound(arrCommands) = 2 Then
      strcurrentPath = Replace(Left(document.location.pathname,InStrRev(document.location.pathname,"\")),"%20"," ")
      strPath = strcurrentPath
    Else
      Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      strLogonServer = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%LogonServer%")
      strPath = strLogonServer & "\" & arrCommands(3) & "\"
    End If

' Uncomment the next line for testing only.
'   Msgbox strPath

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
    If oFSO.fileexists(strPath & strMOTDFile) Then
      Set objFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(strPath & strMOTDFile, ForReading)
      Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objFile.ReadLine
        strContents = strContents & strLine & "<BR>"
      Loop
      objFile.Close
      document.getelementbyid("textarea").innerHTML = strContents 
    Else
      ExitProgram
    End If

    posBtn
    document.body.onresize = GetRef("posBtn")

    Set WshShell = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
  End Sub

  Sub posBtn
    Dim btn, bod, leftLoc
    Set btn=document.getelementbyid("runbutton")
    Set bod=document.getelementbyid("mainbody")
    leftLoc = (bod.offsetWidth/2) - (btn.offsetWidth/2)
    btn.style.position="absolute"
    btn.style.posLeft = leftLoc
  End Sub

  Sub ExitProgram
    window.close()
  End Sub
</SCRIPT>

<body id="mainbody">
<center><h1>Message of the Day</h1></center>
<h3>Important notice:</h3>
<p id="textarea"></p>
<BR>
<BR>
<input id=runbutton type="button" value="I have read and understood this message." onClick="ExitProgram">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry can't use IE9 compatibility, must have a full replacement method